# Openlayer with big data

Tags: javascript, openlayers, gis, geojson

Hi I work with GIS Project and I am using `Openlayer` framework. It works fine with small data (1000 `Poligon` ,`Line` or `Point`) but I have 2 millions `Geometry Object` in `GeoJson` format . It is very slow . I have googled but suggestion not found. Please tell me what happens in such situations? What can I do?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Maybe generate the layer server side (Geoserver or so) and show it in openlayers with WMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with large datasets, you can import them into a Spatial Database like PostGIS, then use Mapserver as a WMS to serve tiled images to OpenLayers.  This way, there are fewer calls to the server, and only a single, relatively small image returned to the browser that is overlayed on the map.  The "work" is shifted to the server and the database.  And with some work, you can cache the images produced, improving speed even more.

Answer (score 0):

Although question is a bit broad you can try several approaches:

Generalization - choosing just most prominent features for given zoom level

Tiling - loading and drawing just those objects that are in current field of view.